# Custom Dropdown or select box using CSS

Tags: css

```
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

this is a normal select box in which when we select one, its value changes to One. But let me know is it possible to set value 1 when I select one
like the image shown down
[image]

I think here we set +297 as the value for the option Aruba
You can also suggest any other alternative way to do so

Comment: It's perfectly possible using a custom dropdown. You have many options available for free or maybe you can built your own one.

Comment: Follow a step-by-step tutorial ;)

Comment: reminds me of select2 - https://select2.org/dropdown